# Approximate Equals in R

Tags: r, if-statement, while-loop, equality

I have to perform an equation on variable i until it 'approximately equals' 100, but I can't seem to get it to work.

By approximately equals, I mean a tolerance of +/-2 on 100.

I have a while(TRUE) loop with a couple of if statements, but I can't seem to get the if's to work correctly.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
PercentageIncrement <- function(RainPerc,Duration) {

 i = RainfallDepthChange(Duration)

 print(paste0("Output: ", i))

 while(TRUE) {

   i = i+(RainPerc*2)

   if (i > 98) { 

     if (i < 102) { 

       break()

     }

   }

   print(paste0("Output: ", i))

 } 

}
```

I've uploaded the whole function to give some context. At the moment, if I run this function with the following inputs:

```
PercentageIncrement(14.29,7)
```

I get the following output:

```
[1] "Output: 14.2857142857143"
[1] "Output: 42.8657142857143"
[1] "Output: 71.4457142857143"
```

This is exactly correct, except for the fact that it is missing a fourth output. In this instance with these inputs, the output should be 100 exactly, but other inputs will vary between 98 and 102.

How might I go about fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: You have strange `if` conditions. Why not simply `if(i > 98 & i < 102)`?

Comment: This still outputs only to 71.4.... and doesn't include 100

Comment: I didn't mean it will solve the problem.

Comment: What is that condition `i > 98 & i < 102` for exactly?  Don't you want `if (i > 102)` ?

Comment: I get that; it's the same thing, simplified. I had a nested 'if' so I could add in a fault-finding output but can't trigger that either, even with an output of 99

Comment: It's not the same at all.

Comment: Hi Matthew- indeed! Sorted, completely overlooked the obvious there, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You're breaking out of the function when it hits 100 so it won't print the number. Just move where the output gets printed and you'll be fine:

```
PercentageIncrement <- function(RainPerc,Duration) {

 i = RainfallDepthChange(Duration)

 print(paste0("Output: ", i))

 while(TRUE) {

   i = i+(RainPerc*2)

   print(paste0("Output: ", i))

   if (i > 98) { 

     if (i < 102) { 

       break()

     }

   }

 } 

}
```

Comment: Why these weird if conditions?

Comment: I just copied and pasted OP's code. It's too late in the evening for me to worry about teaching people proper coding style...